# Using Java 8 with android api 22

Tags: java, android, java-8

I'm using android studio 3.0.0 Beta 5 and according to [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) I should be able to use some Java 8 features for any SDK version.
But instead, I'm getting this exception for the targeted SDK 22:

> default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >=
>   24

While in the previous link, it is said that Default and static interface methods features is available for any SDK.

PS: the dependency using Java 8 is [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/)

Comment: Based on that error message, my guess is that it is a documentation bug. Or, perhaps, it's a change due to the switch from the Jack-based Java 8 support to the newer `javac`-based Java 8 support.

Comment: In the link you provided it says about 24 SDK not the 22.

Comment: @Mike the link says that some are available for any SDK (no minimal SDK constraint) and some need of course at least SDK 24

Comment: You must be doing something wrong in your project configuration. Default & static interface methods definitely *do* work with the *desugar* toolchain in Android Studio 3.0. I have tested that with `compileSdkVersion 26`, `minSdkVersion 15` and `targetSdkVersion 23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minSdk for default and static interface methods is 24. You can see the overview here

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

But it should be available with the new Android Studio 3 according to the table here

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

So it's either a documentation error or it's not ready yet.

Comment: You're right! Both documentations are not saying the same thing... I hope that one of the Android developers working on this could give me the final answer...

Comment: With respect to "of not being ready": most of this worked (for me) already in the alpha-4 build. I'm on beta-6 now and haven't found any bugs yet.

Comment: Old "jack" compiler is deprecated. Now using new "default toolchain" you are able to use "Default and static interface methods" with any version of android min sdk.